# while creating a table using changlog file in liquibase it shows error

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, liquibase, liquid-layout, liquibase-sql

While creating a table in snowflake using the sql queries with changelog file in liquibase.In the schema DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK has created. But its shows the following error:

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: SQL compilation error:
> Object 'DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK' already exists. [Failed SQL: (2002) CREATE TABLE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP_NTZ, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID))]

Answer (score 0):

there is already  saved your `sql script file` or `changeset of xml file` for liquibase in `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` table in database.

`Resolution`: you need to `DELETE` related row in `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` table in database